# ReactJS: How to map an array when calling an action

Tags: arrays, reactjs

I have this function, which has `this.state.brands`. `this.state.brands` contains an array. An array of the values of the checkboxes that are checked.

```
getBrand = (e) => {
    var checked = !e ? false : e.target.checked
    var name = !e ? "" : e.target.name

    if(checked){
        this.setState({
            brands: [name, ...this.state.brands]
        }, () => {
            this.filterBrands()
        })
    }else{
        this.setState({
            brands: this.state.brands.filter((item) => item !== name)
        }, () => {
            this.filterBrands()
        })
    }

}
```

so for example, I checked 2 checkboxes, I have this.state.brands = [ "item1", "item2" ] now, I want to put that array inside this:

```
filterBrands = () => {
    var brands = this.state.brands
    var { brandName, brand } = this.props.params
    this.props.getBrandCategoryProducts(brand + "/" + brandName + "?" + ???);
    //What do I need to put in the ???

}
```

this is what is supposed to be in that "???":

> taxonomy_type[0]=brand&taxonomy[0]=item1&taxonomy_type[1]=brand&taxonomy[1]=item2

But I don't want that hardcoded, I need to map it. I need the length of the array, and in that length depends how many  `taxonomy_type[n]=brand&taxonomy[n]=arrayvalue` would append the url. and I would also append the array value in `arrayvalue`. How can I do that?

EDIT: I tried this, but it doesn't work

```
    filterBrands = () => {
    var brands = this.state.brands
    var { brandName, brand } = this.props.params
    var array = Array.from({length: brands },(v,k)=>k+1)
    this.props.getBrandCategoryProducts(brand + "/" + brandName + "?" + 
        brands.map((name)=>(array.map((item) => 
        "taxonomy_type[" + {item} + "]=brand&taxonomy[" + 
        {item} + "]=" + {name} + "&"))));

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
filterBrands = async() => {
    var brands = this.state.brands
    console.log(brands)
    var { brandName, brand } = this.props.params
    var obj = ""
    var brandsMap = await brands.forEach((name, i)=>{
            console.log(name)
            obj = obj + "taxonomy_type[" + i + "]=brand&taxonomy[" + i + "]=" + name + "&"
        }
    )
    this.props.getBrandCategoryProducts(brand + "/" + brandName + "?" + obj)
    this.setState({
        obj: obj
    })
}
```

it works :)

Comment: the other answer given also works, and is way more succinct.   The reduce method is VERY powerful and it is exactly intended for what you are doing; it's the right way to solve your problem.   Also, why are you using await?  Even if it doesn't have a bad effect here, it is totally unnecessary, and it really confuses what's going on.

Comment: I am also scratching my head wondering why you'd put the query string text (obj) into this.state.   Maybe, the result of getBrandCategoryProducts goes into state, but not obj.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to reduce an array down to a string.
This should do the trick.

```
const str = brands.reduce( (a,c,i) => 
     `${a+(i==0?"?":"&")}taxonomy_type[${i}]=brand&taxonomy[${i}]=${c}`, ""
);
```